# IntersectionObserver: how rootMargin work?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I want intercep an intersection when the target element is at 100px from the intersection root

[image]

for make it, i have setted rootMargin with '100px 0px 100px 0px'.

In this example the intersection become when the first pixel of target element (red box) enter into the intersetion root

[image]

i want the intersetion become when the target element is at 100px from the intersection root (grey area)

```js
    var io = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries){
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =  entries[0].isIntersecting ? 'isIntersecting = true' : 'isIntersecting = false'; 
    }, {
      rootMargin: '100px 0px 100px 0px'
    });
    io.observe(document.getElementById('target'));
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pad {
  height: 1000px;
}

#target {
  background: rgb(237, 28, 36);
  height: 100px;
  outline: 100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#info {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="pad"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
<div class="pad"></div>
<span id="info">isIntersecting = true</span>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default the root is a document viewport which is not direct ancestor of #target element.
To make it work you must specify the root element.
According to [specification](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#intersectionobserver-implicit-root):

> Note: rootMargin only applies to the intersection root itself. If a
> target Element is clipped by an ancestor other than the intersection
> root, that clipping is unaffected by rootMargin.

```js
var io = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = entries[0].isIntersecting ? 'isIntersecting = true' : 'isIntersecting = false';
}, {
  root: document.querySelector('.container'),
  rootMargin: '100px 0px 100px 0px'
});
io.observe(document.getElementById('target'));
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.pad {
  height: 1000px;
}

#target {
  background: rgb(237, 28, 36);
  height: 100px;
  outline: 100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#info {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pad"></div>
  <div id="target"></div>
  <div class="pad"></div>
</div>
<span id="info">isIntersecting = true</span>
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Artem_Bozhko/2cdtk0uf/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result by specifying `document` for the `root` property. I've [forked Arterm's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bradchoate/ozxs1rc9/) to demonstrate.